# Java compiler error when trying to override superclass interface

Tags: java

I don't understand why I'm getting a compiler error when I try and override the push method below.

The exact output error in Eclipse is "Name clash: The method push(T) of type stackImplementation has the same erasure as push(Object) of type stack but does not override it"

```
public interface stack<T> {
    T pop();
    void push(Object t);
}

public class stackImplementation<T> implements stack{

    private final Deque<T> deque = new ArrayDeque<T>();

    @Override
    public T pop() {
        return deque.removeFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public void push(T t) {
        deque.addFirst(t);
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 errors:

1. push in interface uses `Object`, but should be `T`:

   `void push(T t);`
2. class implements `stack`, but should `stack<T>`:

   `class stackImplementation<T> implements stack<T> {`

Comment: Nice catch on #2, but it's confusing to say it implements `stack<?>`.  `stack` is a raw type, and I don't think it's the same as a wildcarded type.

Comment: You're right! I actually did have my push method using T instead of Object, I guess I copied over a wrong version before posting. And implementing stack<T> was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should...

```
@Override
public void push(Object t) {
    deque.addFirst(t);
}
```

Comment: ... or change interface to `void push(T t);`

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to override interface method, to override method

change this:

```
@Override
public void push(T t) {
    deque.addFirst(t);
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void push(Object t) {
    deque.addFirst(t);
}
```

Also implements should look like this:

```
public class stackImplementation<T> implements stack<T>
{
  ......
}
```